# How to compare a symbol with a symbol taken from a list

Tags: racket

If I compare two symbols using `equal?` I get different results depending on whether one of the symbols is from a list and one is not.

This is demonstrated below:

```
; The following returns #t  
(equal? (list-ref '('a 'b) 1) (list-ref '('a 'b) 1))

; But this return #f
(equal? 'b (list-ref '('a 'b) 1))
```

What is the best way to compare two symbols when one is from a list and one is not?  If you can help me understand why this is the case then even better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You weren't comparing symbols:

```
> (list-ref '('a 'b) 1)
''b
> (symbol? (list-ref '('a 'b) 1))
#f
```

due to double quoting:

```
> (list-ref '(a b) 1)
'b
> (symbol? (list-ref '(a b) 1))
#t
```

So your initial case becomes

```
> (equal? 'b (list-ref '(a b) 1))
#t
```

If your list only contains symbols, it's more common to use eq? to compare them (it's supposed to be faster):

```
> (eq? 'b (list-ref '(a b) 1))
#t
```

If you double quoted because your list may contain other types, then use

```
> (list 'a 'b)
'(a b)
```

instead of

```
> '(a b)
'(a b)
```

Comment: Early on, quoted lists can be confusing. In the meantime, you'll rarely go wrong using `list` as in Chris' example, you're more likely to write what you meant.